# Supabase - Subscribing to PostgreSQL failed: {:error, "Error parsing `filter` params

Tags: postgresql, real-time, supabase

I'm trying to set up [event subscriptions](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/subscribe) for my Supabase database using:

```
  const userId = session.data.session.user.id;

  supabaseListener = supabase
    .channel("balance")
    .on(
      "postgres_changes",
      {
        event: "UPDATE",
        schema: "public",
        table: "users",
        filter: `id=eq.${userId}`,
      },
      handleRecordUpdated
    )
    .subscribe();

  return () => {
    authListener.unsubscribe();
    if (supabaseListener) {
      supabaseListener.unsubscribe();
    }
  };
```

E.g. `` console.log(`id=eq.${userId}`) `` logs `id=eq.f96efe56-ff22-4fc4-abc1-abc1` and if I log the userId type on it's own then it's a string.

Inside useEffect, to replicate this snippet from the docs:

```
supabase
  .channel('any')
  .on('postgres_changes', { event: 'UPDATE', schema: 'public', table: 'countries', filter: 'id=eq.200' }, handleRecordUpdated)
  .subscribe()
```

But I'm getting an error in the realtime logs:

> Subscribing to PostgreSQL failed: {:error, "Error parsing `filter` params: ["f96efe56-ff22-4fc4-abc1-abc1"]"}

The ID matches an ID in the database so I'm not sure what's going wrong here?

Comment: It looks like you are passing an array as the filter parameter rather than a single userId. Make sure the `userId` variable is a string with a single user ID value.

Comment: @dshukertjr thanks, I've just updated my post to mention this - when I log `userId` it has a typeof `string` and is shown as a string so I'm not sure why it's being formatted as an array when it's used in the filter criteria?